# The equivalent of wrap_content and match_parent in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

In Android `match_parent` and `wrap_content` are used to resize the widgets automatically relative to their parent to the content the widget contains.

In Flutter it seems by default all widgets are set to `wrap_content`, how would I change it such that I can fill its `width` and `height` to that of its parent?

Answer (score 475, accepted):

> *Note: Default behaviour of parent widget is to fill all the space available with its child. Scafold>body:Container(sized) is different the
> Scafold>body:Center>Container(Sized)*
> You can read more about it https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints

> Understanding This will will clear all you concept how widget works : **Constrains go down sizes go up parent set position**

You can do with little Trick:
Suppose you have requirement of :
**( Width,Height )**

**Wrap_content ,Wrap_content :**

```
 //use this as child
 Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[*your_child*])
```

**Match_parent,Match_parent:**

```
 //use this as child
Container(
        height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,child:*your_child*)
```

**Match_parent,Wrap_content :**

```
 //use this as child
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[*your_child*],
);
```

**Wrap_content ,Match_parent:**

```
 //use this as child
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[your_child],
);
```

> > Note: In order to understand how a widget lay its children && repaint you can look into package ***[be_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/be_widgets)*** source code
> > I developed it to reduce the nesting widget tree & improve performance.

Comment: to the match the parent you could also wrap your Widgets with SizedBox.expand()

Comment: I do agree with all but one cases. `Wrap_content ,Wrap_content` one is handled by design by Flutter (which is great, you don't need to assign no _width_ nor _height_ every time). `Wrap` has different usage, explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M

Comment: @PrzemekTom I do agree with you that's why i have updated my answer how parent lay its children based on constrains of parent and child

Answer (score 269):

> In order to get behavior for *match_parent* and *wrap_content* we need to
>   use **mainAxisSize** property in *Row/Column* widget, the **mainAxisSize**
>   property takes **MainAxisSize** enum having two values which is
>   **MainAxisSize.min** which behaves as *wrap_content* and **MainAxisSize.max**
>   which behaves as *match_parent*.

[image]

[Link](https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-for-android-developers-how-to-design-linearlayout-in-flutter-5d819c0ddf1a) of the original Article

Comment: I would add that there's also the `crossAxisAlignment` field on Rows and Columns that can be set to `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to expand horizontally within a Column for example

Comment: great answer! If anyone is looking for more such examples then use the following link
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Comment: You're a hero..

Answer (score 47):

The short answer is that the parent doesn't have a size until the child has a size.

The way layout works in Flutter is that each widget provides constraints to each of its children, like "you can be up to this wide, you must be this tall, you have to be at least this wide", or whatever (specifically, they get a minimum width, a maximum width, a minimum height, and a maximum height). Each child takes those constraints, does something, and picks a size (width and height) that matches those constraints. Then, once each child has done its thing, the widget can can pick its own size.

Some widgets try to be as big as the parent allows. Some widgets try to be as small as the parent allows. Some widgets try to match a certain "natural" size (e.g. text, images).

Some widgets tell their children they can be any size they want. Some give their children the same constraints that they got from their parent.

Comment: Ian, when I have a `PageView` inside a `Column`, with another `Column` inside the current `page`, I get a rendering error, but I can fix it by wrapping the `PageView` inside an `Expanded` or a `Flexible`. The problem is, those 2 options only expand their child. Why isn't there related widget to shrink go fit, like "wrap content", for solving this kind of rendering issues?

Comment: This behavior is similar to Android Jetpack Compose UI toolkit

Answer (score 33):

There are actually some options available:

You can use SizedBox.expand to make your widget match parents dimensions, or SizedBox(width: double.infinity) to match only the width or SizedBox(heigth: double.infinity) to match only the heigth.

If you want a wrap_content behavior it depends on the parent widget you are using, for example if you put a button on a column it will behave like wrap_content and to use it like match_parent you can wrap the button with a Expanded widget or a sizedbox.

With a ListView the button gets a match_parent behavior and to get a wrap_content behavior you can wrap it with a Flex widget like Row.

Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex
expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for
a Row or vertically for a Column).
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Using a Flexible widget gives a child of a Row, Column, or Flex the flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column), but, unlike Expanded, Flexible does not require the child to fill the available space.
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Answer (score 26):

Use the widget **`Wrap`**.

For **`Column`** like behavior try:

```
  return Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          spacing: 10,
          children: <Widget>[...],);
```

For **`Row`** like behavior try:

```
  return Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          spacing: 10,
          children: <Widget>[...],);
```

For more information: [Wrap (Flutter Widget)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M)

Answer (score 16):

To make a child fill its parent, simply wrap it into a FittedBox

```dart
    FittedBox(
     child: Image.asset('foo.png'),
     fit: BoxFit.fill,
   )
```

Answer (score 14):

I used this solution, you have to define the height and width of your screen using MediaQuery:

```
 Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
  )
```

Comment: This solution has strong lack if the content is  higher than the screen height it throws overflow ex.

Answer (score 10):

**A simple workaround:**

If a container has only one top level child, then you can specify alignment property for the child and give it any available value. it'll fill all the space in the container.

```
Container(color:Colors.white,height:200.0,width:200.0,
 child:Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    alignment:Alignment.[any_available_option] // make the yellow child match the parent size
   )
)
```

**Another way:**

```
Container(color:Colors.white,height:200.0,width:200.0,
 child:Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    constraints:  BoxConstraints.expand(height: 100.0), // height will be 100 dip and width will be match parent
   )
)
```

Comment: `BoxConstraints.expand(height: 100.0)` works great as Android's `width="match_parent"` equivalent

Answer (score 10):

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(color:Colors.red, height:200.0, width:200.0),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Container(color: Colors. yellow),
    )
  ]
),
```

Comment: Although your code might answer the question, a good answer should always explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: this is not answer to wrap content. this is simply hard coded width and height.

Answer (score 8):

Use `FractionallySizedBox` widget.

```dart
FractionallySizedBox(
  widthFactor: 1.0, // width w.r.t to parent
  heightFactor: 1.0,  // height w.r.t to parent
  child: *Your Child Here*
}
```

This widget is also very useful when you want to size your child at a fraction of its parent's size.

> Example:
>
> If you want the child to occupy 50% width of its parent, provide `widthFactor` as `0.5`

Answer (score 6):

**MATCH_PARENT**

[image]

```
FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1.0, // width w.r.t to parent
            heightFactor: 1.0, // height w.r.t to parent

            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("+"),
            ),
          )
```

OR

```
Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

OR

```
Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

OR

```
Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

**WRAP_CONTENT**

[image]

```
Wrap(children: [
          Container(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("+"),
            ),
          ),
        ])
```

OR

```
Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

**Match_parent,Wrap_content** :
[image]

```
Row(
            children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("+"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ])
```

**Wrap_content,Match_parent** :
[image]

```
Column(
            children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("+"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this line of codes inside the Column.
For wrap_content : `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`
For match_parent : `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`

Answer (score 5):

## Match Parent

To match or fill the parent (height & width) we can use additional `constraints` on `Container`:

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(), // ← this guy
  child: Text('Center > Container > Text')
)
```

In Flutter, `constraints` are the space you can fill (or *must* fill, if "tight" constraints).

Constraints are <strike>given</strike>... no actually, *imposed* by parents.

By default, `Container` will wrap its content (`child:`) & size itself to its child, unless overriden (or not allowed by tight constraints).

Using the `constraints:` argument, we can give `Container` *additional* constraints to override default `Container` constraint behavior (such as wrapping content).

Using `Container(constraints: BoxConstraints.something)` **doesn't overwrite incoming/parent constraints**; It just allows us to override default behavior, where allowed, such as wrapping content.

---

### Code Sample - `BoxConstraints`

Here's a copy/paste code example showing effects of various `constraints` we can apply to a `Container` that has "loose" incoming/parental constraints (provided by `Center`).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MatchParentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MatchParentPageState createState() => _MatchParentPageState();
}

class _MatchParentPageState extends State<MatchParentPage> {
  BoxConstraints constraints;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Match Parent'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Expanded( // shares space constraint evenly with other Expanded
            child: Center( // ← fills tight parent constraint & loosens ↓ child constraint ↓
              child: Container( // got loose constraint from Center... 
                  constraints: constraints, // can apply many additional constraints
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(.3),
                  child: Text('Center > Container > Text')),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                child: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      _button('default', null),
                      _button('*expand()', BoxConstraints.expand()),
                      _button('*tight(Size.infinite)', BoxConstraints.tight(Size.infinite)),
                      _button('tight(Size.zero)', BoxConstraints.tight(Size.zero)),
                      _button('tight(Size.fromHeight(100))', BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromHeight(100))),
                      _button('tight(Size.fromWidth(100))', BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromWidth(100))),
                      _button('tightForFinite(width: 100, height: 100)', BoxConstraints.tightForFinite(width: 100, height: 100)),
                      _button('loose(Size.infinite)', BoxConstraints.loose(Size.infinite)),
                      _button('tightFor(width: double.infinity)', BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: double.infinity)),
                      _button('tightFor(height: double.infinity)', BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: double.infinity)),
                    ])
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _button(String label, BoxConstraints _constraints) {
    bool _active = _constraints == constraints;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8, left: 8),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: _active ? Colors.cyanAccent : null,
        child: Text(label),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => constraints = _constraints);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For match parent option you can wrap your widget by a container and give it a width like this

`width: double.infinity`

this approach will make the widget fill max space available for it on the screen.