# How to make flutter TextField height match parent of container?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make my `TextField` height the same as my container height. Please check my code below and let me know how can I make `TextField` match_parent of my container. I've checked this question [The equivalent of wrap_content and match_parent in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257668/the-equivalent-of-wrap-content-and-match-parent-in-flutter) but I didn't find any solution. I need to make `TextField` to take full height and width of my container.

```
 new Container(
            height: 200.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black)
            ),

            child: new SizedBox.expand(
              child: new TextField(
                maxLines: 2,
                style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                   // height: 2.0,
                    color: Colors.black
                ),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "There is no data",
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                  )
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Please check the screenshot below. As said, I need my `TextField` to take full height of `Container`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The equivalent of wrap\_content and match\_parent in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257668/the-equivalent-of-wrap-content-and-match-parent-in-flutter)

Answer (score 12):

Here is my solution:

```
Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: 200.0,
              ),
              child: new Scrollbar(
                child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  reverse: true,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 190.0,
                    child: new TextField(
                      maxLines: 100,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Add your text here',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

It works pretty good for me. And here is a screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Answering this in 2021. There is an `expands` property available now. This code works:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          maxLines: null, 
          minLines: null, 
          expands: true,
        ), 
        flex: 1),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's remove a few lines in code and understand how flutter works.

1. Why we are giving height `200` to **Container**. Can't the `Container` adjust the height based on its child (in this case SizedBox.expand)
2. If we remove height 200, then `Container` occupied the **entire screen** because of `SizedBox.expand`
3. Do we really need the `SizedBox` for our use case. Let's remove that also see what happens.
4. Now our `Container` wraps the `TextField`. But there is some space above and below.
5. Who decided that space? TextField's decoration's contentPadding. Let's remove that also. It looks like below where textField wrapped by Container. Hope this is what you want. If not, please comment, we can tweak a bit and get what you want. Cheers
   [image]

Final version of code which displays the above image

```
 new Container(
   //   height: 200.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black)
      ),

      child: new TextField(
          maxLines: 2,
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              // height: 2.0,
              color: Colors.black
          ),
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: "There is no data",
//                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
          )
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh, actually I need a fixed height of my `Container` and to make my `TextFiled` to take this height.

Comment: Hi Ammy, How are you giving height to your TextField ?

Comment: currently I am using `maxline` attribute to give height to `TextField`, but this is not a good a practice.

Comment: Got it.. 1) It is highly coupled with fontSize. 2) I am not sure whether it will affect if you change the device (like tablet, iPad). For now, it solves the problem. Have a eye on above two problems.

Comment: Yes, I know problems may occur, this is temporary fix for now, can you please help me with this? I need to make my container height fix all time.

Comment: I will try my best to help. Can you share the UI requirements/mockups ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177717/discussion-between-ammy-kang-and-dinesh-balasubramanian).

Comment: Did you two find a solution? I am unable to make a TextField automatically size its height to fit inside a flexible height container.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to achieve the `TextField` to fill the available vertical space is:

```
TextField(maxLines: 1000000) //maxlines: any large int
```

While it is tempting to use `TextField(maxLines: null)`, it will just set the `TextField` to expand with its content, until it reaches its container limit.

I think there needs to be a `bool stretchVertically` parameter. `TextField(stretchVertically: true)` would mean that the `TextField` will try to fill as much vertical space as it can. `stretchVertically` and `maxLines` would have to be mutually exclusive.