# Row match parent width

Tags: layout, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to make the `Row` containing "Short label" wide as the `Row` below it.

Putting `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` isn't enought, since it should match parent width, based on this answer:
[The equivalent of wrap_content and match_parent in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257668/the-equivalent-of-wrap-content-and-match-parent-in-flutter)

Tried using `Expanded` outside row, but it causes an error, same using `SizedBox.expand`.
Can't use constraints like `width: double.infinity` because the row on the left (`// Left part` in code) must take only the space it needs, the rest must be taken from the yellow container.

Screenshot and code below:

[image: App screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                // Left part
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Column(children: [
                      // Error using Expanded ...
                      //Expanded(
                      //child:
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text('Short label:'),
                          Container(width: 20, height: 20, color: Colors.red),
                        ],
                      ),
                      //),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text('Long text label:'),
                          Container(width: 20, height: 20, color: Colors.red),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**EDIT (old, check final edit below)**

`IntrinsicWidth` was the correct way to give the rows the same width, as @mohandes suggests.

But it does not work if i add another row below (the one containing the checkbox in the image below), wrapping the rows inside two `IntrinsicWidth` widgets.
The checkbox row should be wide as the upper one in order to align the checkbox on the left.

In the first row i added an orange container on the right as a placeholder for a similar block.

Screenshot and code below:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  IntrinsicWidth(
                    child: Row(children: [
                      IntrinsicWidth(
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Text('Short label 1:'),
                              Container(width: 20, height: 20, color: Colors.red),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Text('Short label 123456:'),
                              Container(width: 20, height: 20, color: Colors.red),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      )
                    ]),
                  ),
                  IntrinsicWidth(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: null),
                        Text('Checkbox'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**EDIT 2**

`IntrinsicWidth` works fine, the problem with the code above in the first Edit is that i used `IntrinsicWidth` as wrapper for child widgets (the rows) instead of parent widget (the outer column).

Comment: If you want to cover full width, why are you using `Row`? If you don't use row, it'll automatically take the full width

Comment: @HardikKumar: you mean Row containing Text and Container (which should become a TextField)? Which widget is more suitable to put more widgets in a row?

Comment: I can't understand what you actually want to achieve? Is it a textfield? Please explain your question properly so that i can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the column that contains rows (long and short) in intrinsic width widget .
Intrinsic width make all children width as longest child width.

Comment: This seems to work at short glance, i'll make another test later and accept your answer!

Comment: Your strategy works for that two rows in my old code, please check my edit, i added an example with one more row where it seems to fail

Comment: I corrected my code in the first edit, IntrinsicWidth works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By changing the layout to `Row [ Column Column Container ]` we get

[image]

Code:

```
Widget alternateLayout() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue[100],
            child: Text('Short label:'),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green[100],
            child: Text('Long text label:'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using two columns the layout would fail depending on row heights. Label and container (which is a placeholder for a complex widget) must be on the same row so that they can be vertical aligned properly. I edited my question with `IntrinsicWidth` widget

Comment: ok yes. @Ansharja Just for info, according to [IntrinsicWidth docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html), it might get computationally expensive (for desktop app that cost might not matter much).